# Finding all strings within a character range

Tags: python, string, format

Suppose I have a list of strings:

```
arr = ['413', '4130', '41398', '412', '41390', '41399', '420', '42000']
```

And I am trying to find which elements in that list fall within the inclusive string "range" ['413', '41399'].

My expected output:

```
['413', '4130', '41398', '41390']
```

What should be *ex*cluded:

```
['412', '420', '42000']
```

Here's my attempt:

```
included = [x for x in arr if int(x) in range(int('413'), int('41399'))]
```

Which gives:

```
['413', '4130', '41398', '41390', '420']
```

While close, this is obviously not the correct output and will perform poorly on a larger list of strings. In SAS, I could do a PROC FORMAT and have the values be `'413'-'41399'`. This would give the desired results. Will I need to resort to using regular expressions in Python, or will it be a matter of using `ord` for each character in the strings in the list?

Comment: Why are you working with strings and not numbers? Why should '420' be excluded?

Comment: These are [ICD-9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ICD-9_codes) codes, and you can see that my attempt to filter in the range using integers did not work (`'420'` is a different code entirely and can't be in the range `['413', '41399']`.

Comment: Ah, I understand. There is alreadya solution posted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can compare strings lexicographically.

```
included = [x for x in arr if '413' <= x < '414']
```

Comment: Great. I knew there was something Pythonesque for this. This is very similar to the PROC FORMAT syntax I suggested above.